# Unable to split the column into multiple columns based on the first column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I've a data frame which contains one column. Below is the example

```
Questionsbysortorder        
        
Q1-4,Q2-3,Q3-2,Q4-3,Q5-3            
Q1-1,Q2-2,Q3-1,Q4-1             
Q1-5,Q2-3,Q3-3
```

I'm trying to explode the columns with the help of already given row values. Like below is the example

```
Questionsbysortorder        Q1    Q2   Q3   Q4   Q5
             
Q1-4,Q2-3,Q3-2,Q4-3,Q5-3    4     3    2    3    3  
Q1-1,Q2-2,Q3-1,Q4-1         1     2    1    1    NA 
Q1-5,Q2-3,Q5-3              5     3    NA   NA   3
```

Below is the code which i tried, but it's returning an error

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Questionsbysortorder': ['Q1-4,Q2-3,Q3-2,Q4-3,Q5-3', 'Q1-1,Q2-2,Q3-1,Q4-1','Q1-5,Q2-3,Q5-3']})

df['Questionsbysortorder'] = df['Questionsbysortorder'].str.split(',')

df = df.explode('Questionsbysortorder')

df['Questionsbysortorder'] = df['Questionsbysortorder'].str.split('-')

df = df.explode('Questionsbysortorder')

df = df.set_index('Questionsbysortorder').unstack().reset_index()

df.columns = ['Questionsbysortorder', 'value']

df = df.pivot(index='Questionsbysortorder', columns='value', values='Questionsbysortorder')

df.columns.name = None

print(df)
```

Error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-30dd8b8d4f59> in <module>()
     14 df = df.set_index('Questionsbysortorder').unstack().reset_index()
     15 
---> 16 df.columns = ['Questionsbysortorder', 'value']
     17 
     18 df = df.pivot(index='Questionsbysortorder', columns='value', values='Questionsbysortorder')

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/base.py in _validate_set_axis(self, axis, new_labels)
     56         elif new_len != old_len:
     57             raise ValueError(
---> 58                 f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_len} elements, new "
     59                 f"values have {new_len} elements"
     60             )

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 2 elements
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. You want to

- split by `','`,
- explode the list,
- split again by `'-'` to get the different fields
- finally pivot the data

In code:

```
df.join(df.Questionsbysortorder.str.split(',')
   .explode()
   .str.split('-', expand=True)
   .set_index(0, append=True)[1]
   .unstack()
)
```

Output:

```
       Questionsbysortorder Q1 Q2 Q3   Q4   Q5
0  Q1-4,Q2-3,Q3-2,Q4-3,Q5-3  4  3  2    3    3
1       Q1-1,Q2-2,Q3-1,Q4-1  1  2  1    1  NaN
2            Q1-5,Q2-3,Q3-3  5  3  3  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

another way to split the column into multiple columns is using str.findall() method, here is an example:

```
res = df.Questionsbysortorder.str.findall(r'(Q\d+)-(\d+)').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(dict(x)))

print(res)
'''
  Q1 Q2   Q3   Q4   Q5
0  4  3    2    3    3
1  1  2    1    1  NaN
2  5  3  NaN  NaN    3
```